# How to specify complex sort property as PageRequest parameter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

My PageRequest is something like this

```
PageRequest pageReq = new PageRequest(0, 1, Direction.DESC, "lastDate-firstDate");
```

but when I run code I get error like this

> "Sort expression 'lastDate - firstDate : DESC' must only contain property references or aliases used in the select clause.

here firstDate and lastDate are the name of entity Columns, and I want to get entity with highest difference in last and first Date.

Any Idea how to that and what is wrong with above code?

Answer (score 0):

Truly complicated sorting is done with something like the following

```
PageRequest.of(0, 1, Sort.by(Arrays.asList(Order.desc("lastDate"), Order.desc("firstDate"))));
```

However something kind of simple like your example can be done with this, since they're all in the same direction.

```
PageRequest.of(0, 1, Direction.DESC, "lastDate", "firstDate");
```

Actually looking at your question again, I think you're trying to order by a difference in the two properties (minus). With that in mind, I suspect you'll need to add that to your select criteria as something like follows.

```
"select lastDate - firstDate as timeDiff FROM table"
```

at which point you can sort by the difference between the two. I suspect that doing this might require you to use an @Query, and will almost definitely require you to use something like findAllOrderBy instead of findAll (IE you need to change the query itself).